# Diagonalization of block anti-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, diagonalization

Matrix $A$ is given in the form,

$ 
  A= \begin{bmatrix}
     0 &  X \\
    Y &  0 
\end{bmatrix}
$

where $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. Why A is diagonalizable?

Note: I think this form of A always appear when writing a second order ODE system into two coupled first order ODEs. It is important when dealing with systems with complex spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

I think the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}
     0 &  X \\
    Y &  0 
\end{bmatrix}$
is similar to $B= \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
     X+Y &  0 \\
    0 &  -X-Y 
\end{bmatrix}$, or something nearby to that.
If the matrices $X$ and $Y$ are symmetric, then so is the matrix $B$. Therefore, $B$ is diagonalizable and it follows that the similar matrix $A$ is diagonalizeable too.

Comment: But how did you know B is similar to A? having the same eigenvalues is not a sufficient condition for A and B to be similar.

Comment: You have to look for a similarity transformation. It usually means that if $A$ is similar to $B$, then there is a unitary matrix $U$ s.t. $A = U BU^{-1}$.